# MSBuild Force Project Reload

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild

One of our projects has an imports statement to pull in some references to a SDK we use. This targets file is not present until we execute a build step in our build xml to copy the file over.

However before we copy the sdk and the targets file over, we execute a clean on the project (msbuild). Apparently this has the side effect of loading the project, and caching the references and the load state. Since this happens before the targets file is copied over, the targets file never gets loaded, and so my build eventually fails.

Is there a way to force a full project reload programatically in the build xml? I can code up a workaround if need be but I would like avoid this if possible.

I'm using VS 2017. The project is a C++ Desktop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can force re-evaluation of a project by passing in a different set of global properties. If you are using the `<MSBuild>` task, add and attribute `Properties="Dummy=Value"` to one of the invocations.

However, this will only work if the targets file did not exist before and does exist now, it will not reload a changed targets file. This is why MSBuild 15.5 introduced a `/restore` argument to execute a `Restore` target, clean all caches, and then perform another build using the targets provided by `/t:` arguments / project defaults.

Comment: Thanks. I looked at the xml schema and didn't see restore as a msbuild attribute. However there is a UnloadProjectsOnCompletion attribute that I think may do the trick. Thanks for the insight for me to look again for this.

Comment: It doesn't always, msbuild caches too aggressively. make sure to use different set of `Properties=""` attributes or create a restore target as mentioned.